# Difference between valid accuracy from CategoricalAccuracy() and manual prediction

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification

I used `CategoricalAccuracy()` to calculate the valid_accuracy during training and reached 0.733 in a certain round. After training, I use the model weights saved under the epoch to predict the same valid data set, and the accuracy obtained is only 0.38. Why is this?

[This is my training log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uox1q.png)

I only divided the data into two sets: **training set** and **validation set**.

There are 517 images in my validation set. I use this model to make manual predictions and compare them with the true labels. Only 199 images are correctly predicted. The accuracy rate is only 0.38, which is less than 0.733.

Even if it is overfitting, I think these two values should be close.

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        step = 0
        for features in train_dataset:
            step += 1
            images, labels = process_features(features, data_augmentation=True)
            train_step(images, labels)
            print("Epoch: {}/{}, step: {}/{}, loss: {:.5f}, accuracy: {:.5f}".format(epoch,
                                                                                     EPOCHS,
                                                                                     step,
                                                                                     math.ceil(train_count / BATCH_SIZE),
                                                                                     train_loss.result().numpy(),
                                                                                     train_accuracy.result().numpy()))

        for features in valid_dataset:
            valid_images, valid_labels = process_features(features, data_augmentation=False)
            valid_step(valid_images, valid_labels)

        print("Epoch: {}/{}, train loss: {:.5f}, train accuracy: {:.5f}, "
              "valid loss: {:.5f}, valid accuracy: {:.5f}".format(epoch,
                                                                  EPOCHS,
                                                                  train_loss.result().numpy(),
                                                                  train_accuracy.result().numpy(),
                                                                  valid_loss.result().numpy(),
                                                                  valid_accuracy.result().numpy()))
```

```
def process_features(features, data_augmentation):
    image_raw = features['image_raw'].numpy()
    image_tensor_list = []
    for image in image_raw:
        image_tensor = load_and_preprocess_image(image, data_augmentation=data_augmentation)
        image_tensor_list.append(image_tensor)
    images = tf.stack(image_tensor_list, axis=0)
    labels = features['label'].numpy()
    new_labels = tf.one_hot(labels,7)

    return images, new_labels
```

```
def load_and_preprocess_image(image_raw, data_augmentation=False):
    # decode
    image_tensor = tf.io.decode_image(contents=image_raw, channels=CHANNELS, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)

    if data_augmentation:
        image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image=image_tensor)
        image = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(image=image,
                                                 target_height=int(IMAGE_HEIGHT * 1.2),
                                                 target_width=int(IMAGE_WIDTH * 1.2))
        image = tf.image.random_crop(value=image, size=[IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, CHANNELS])
        image = tf.image.random_brightness(image=image, max_delta=0.5)
    else:
        image = tf.image.resize(image_tensor, [IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH])

    return image
```

```
def valid_step(image_batch, label_batch):
        predictions = model(image_batch, training=False)
        v_loss = loss_object(label_batch, predictions)

        valid_loss.update_state(values=v_loss)
        valid_accuracy.update_state(y_true=label_batch, y_pred=predictions)
```

The following is my code to detect each picture of **validation set**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from configuration import save_model_dir, test_image_dir
from prepare_data import load_and_preprocess_image
from train import get_model


def get_single_picture_prediction(model, picture_dir):
    image_tensor = load_and_preprocess_image(tf.io.read_file(filename=picture_dir), data_augmentation=False)
    image = tf.expand_dims(image_tensor, axis=0)
    prediction = model(image, training=False)
    pred_class = tf.math.argmax(prediction, axis=-1)
    return pred_class


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # GPU settings
    gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    if gpus:
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

    # load the model
    model = get_model()
    model.load_weights(filepath=save_model_dir+"model")

    pred_class = get_single_picture_prediction(model, test_image_dir)
    print(pred_class)
```

[This is my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uox1q.png)

Comment: Can we see your code? That would help to spot the error, otherwise it's just guessing. Could it be the case that you're doing some preprocessing before training which you forgot to do when loading the weights and predicting again.

Comment: OK, thanks for your advice.
I have added my code to the question.
I guess there may be no preprocessing problem, because the valid_accuracy obtained during model training and I reload the model to predict a single image using the same function `load_and_preprocess_image()`.

Comment: Thanks for providing the code. Preprocessing seems fine as far as I can tell, but I'm not sure what kind of objects `valid_accuracy` and `valid_loss` are? You call `.update_state()` on them within the `valid_step()` method. Can you provide some more detail on that?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
According to your thoughts, I found the cause of the problem. When I tested the accuracy during the training process, i only used part of the data in the validation set in each epoch , but in the final test, all the validation sets were used, resulting in a mismatch in accuracy.

Comment: You're welcome. Nice to hear you found the bug ;)

Comment: By the way, could you help me explain why my accuracy is showing such a trend? Thanks again.(I have attached the picture at the end of the question.)

Comment: What's wrong with it? Accuracy for train and validation is increasing with increasing number of epochs you trained, your networks learn to predict things correct. Validation is not decreasing, so no overfitting. Looks fine to me. Do you mean the spikes in validation accuracy?